# SQL Server and Oracle query ignoring accents

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, diacritics

I have a table called A and a column called Keywords Varchar(255). The Keywords column can contain strings like "TEST, CÃO, ódio" and so on... with or without accents:

```
ID  Keywords
1   TEST, CÃO, ódio, oracle, SQL, açaí
2   Valor, Deputado Rafael, Costelão, estilo
3   São Sebastião, cao, projeto de lei
```

I'm trying to create a SQL query that compare strings ignoring brazilian accents (áéíóúç and so on...). So if the user searches for "cao", it should return the rows 1 and 3 in the example.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT keywords
FROM A WHERE UPPER(TRANSLATE(keywords,  
'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëü','ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeu'))
LIKE UPPER((TRANSLATE('%cao%',
  'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëü', 'ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeu')));
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried using NLS_SORT, but it is only for Oracle, and I need a query that works both on SQL Server and Oracle (it's a client requirement). How can I do that?

Comment: "*I need a query that works both on SQL Server and Oracle*" - not possible

Comment: This has to do with the collation that was chosen on the column, you have the option with most collations to choose an accent insensitive collation although this is usually not the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that Microsoft SQL Server did not have a translate function until 2017.  It does now, but since it doesn't work for you, you are probably not on this version yet.

You can do a nested replace instead.  This is not difficult but is tedious to write.  Once it is written and tested, it will be fine.

The Microsoft SQL Server documentation explains this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql

You also should be aware of the character encoding that is being used in Oracle and SQL Server.  With the translate and replace functions you should be OK, but if you ever transfer data via files it will be important.  I have described more of this at: http://www.thedatastudio.net/dodgy_characters.htm

Here's an example for the first few characters you want to translate:

```
select
  replace
  (
    replace
    (
      replace
      (
        replace
        (
          'ABÇDÉFGHÍJÁBÇDÉFGHÍJ', 'Á', 'A'
        ), 'Ç', 'C'
      ), 'É', 'E'
    ), 'Í', 'I'
  ) as clean_keyword;
```

Just substitute your keyword for 'ABÇDÉFGHÍJÁBÇDÉFGHÍJ'.

The result is:

```
ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ
```

There is an example on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql too.

Comment: How nested replace works? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I tried, like this:

select
  replace
  (
    replace
    (
      replace
      (
        replace
        (
          Keywords, 'Ã', 'A'
        ), 'Ç', 'C'
      ), 'É', 'E'
    ), 'Á', 'A'
  ) as clean_keyword FROM A  WHERE UPPER(Keywords) LIKE UPPER('%COSTELAO%')  

but it doesn't return any row. It should return the second row (ID = 2)

Comment: Did you mean to translate  'Ã' to 'O'?  I don't know if that's right.  Could you select the untranslated  version and the translated version in the same query so that we can see what is happening, please?  Was this on Oracle?  did you try also on SQL Server?

Comment: @aseolin: `WHERE UPPER(Keywords) LIKE UPPER('%COSTELAO%')`? Don't you rather want to look up the clean keyword? `select keywords FROM A WHERE UPPER(replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( keywords, 'Ã', 'A' ), 'Ç', 'C' ), 'É', 'E' ), 'Á', 'A' )) LIKE '%COSTELAO%'`.

Comment: This is working as expected but only in Oracle. In SQL server no rows is returned, even with another keywords. anyway, if the keyword has accent (like "COSTELÃO"), it doesn't work

Comment: Replace does work with SQL Server, so can you select the original and the translated keyword, please, and show us that?

Comment: replace works on SQL server..see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp

Comment: Here is my example that does not return any row: select Keywords FROM A WHERE UPPER(replace ( replace ( replace ( replace ( Keywords, 'Ã', 'A' ), 'Ç', 'C' ), 'É', 'E' ), 'Á', 'A' )) LIKE '%COSTELÃO%'

Comment: In that last query you are comparing the cleaned keyword with a literal string containing one of the characters that we translated ('Ã') so it won't match.

Comment: I got it. Is was a encoding problem.

Comment: Great, I'm glad we go there in the end.  Thanks for the check mark.